# Import and Export Core Module and Shared Module

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

I'm having a difficulty in determining on what should i "import" and "export" in my core modules and shared modules. For instance, in my shared module, i imported and exported CommonModule while only exported the ReactiveFormsModule. In my core module, i imported modules and exported components only. I'm wondering what should i "import" and "export" in core and shared module? I've read other examples here in stackoverflow and the docs and I'm still confuse. Please check my structure/codes below. Thanks.

> Shared Module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ToggleFullscreenDirective } from './directives/toggle-fullscreen.directive';
import { ViewComponent } from './view/view.component';
import { ErrorsComponent } from './reusable-error-page/errors.component';

@NgModule({
  exports: [
    ToggleFullscreenDirective,
    ViewComponent,
    ErrorsComponent,
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    ToggleFullscreenDirective,
    ViewComponent,
    ErrorsComponent
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

> Core Module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpRequestInterceptor } from './http-request.interceptor';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { SidebarComponent } from './sidebar/sidebar.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { AuthModule } from '@app/auth/auth.module';
import { NgSelectModule } from '@ng-select/ng-select';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ContentLayoutComponent } from '../layouts/content/content-layout.component';
import { FullLayoutComponent } from '../layouts/full/full-layout.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from '../page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
import { ErrorPageComponent } from '../error-page/error-page.component';

// NGXS
import { NgxsModule } from '@ngxs/store';
import { NgxsReduxDevtoolsPluginModule } from '@ngxs/devtools-plugin';
import { NgxsLoggerPluginModule } from '@ngxs/logger-plugin';
import { NgxsStoragePluginModule } from '@ngxs/storage-plugin';
import { NgxsRouterPluginModule } from '@ngxs/router-plugin';
import { NGXS_PLUGINS } from '@ngxs/store';
import { logoutPlugin } from '@app/auth/plugins/logout.plugin';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    NavbarComponent,
    SidebarComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    FullLayoutComponent,
    ContentLayoutComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent,
    ErrorPageComponent
  ],

  imports: [
    AuthModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NgSelectModule,
    RouterModule,
    NgbModule,
    NgxsReduxDevtoolsPluginModule.forRoot(),
    NgxsLoggerPluginModule.forRoot(),
    NgxsModule.forRoot(),
    NgxsStoragePluginModule.forRoot(),
    NgxsRouterPluginModule.forRoot()
  ],

  exports: [
    NavbarComponent,
    SidebarComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    FullLayoutComponent,
    ContentLayoutComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent,
    ErrorPageComponent
  ],

  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: HttpRequestInterceptor, multi: true },
    {
      provide: NGXS_PLUGINS,
      useValue: logoutPlugin,
      multi: true
    }
  ]

})
export class CoreModule { }
```

> App Module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { ServiceWorkerModule } from '@angular/service-worker';
import { environment } from '@env/environment';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    CoreModule,
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production })
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 8):

There is a specific purpose of each module (Shared, Core etc..).

So the question is what package should I import in `Shared Module` and what in the `Core Module`.

**So suppose of an application which has the following modules:**

1. App Module
2. Core Module
3. Shared Module
4. User Module `(This is called feature module)`
5. Admin Module `(This is called feature module)`

**Let's describe it:**

> 1. App Module

In this module, we have to import the modules/packages which we will use throughout our system. Like: `CommonModule, FormsModule, HttpClientModule` etc. And we don't need to export these modules as it will be available in whole application once it is imported in App Module.

> 2. Core Module

In this module, we have to make components which will be used in almost every page of the system. Like: `HeaderComponent`, `FooterCompoennt`, `AuthGaurds` etc. And these components should be exported so that it will be available in other modules.

> 3. Shared Module

In this module, we have to make the `Services, Components, Pipes, and Directives` which will be used in more than one component. Like: `AlertDialogBox`, `HTTPService`, etc.

> 4. User Module

This is a featured module. It will have the components specific to a User Module. Here we can import Shared Module so that we can use `AlertDialogBox` and all.

> 5. Admin Module

This is a featured module. It will have the components specific to a User Module. Here we can import Shared Module so that we can use `AlertDialogBox` and all.

Comment: Can you rewrite my core, shared and app module for better clarification? Thanks

Comment: I'm lazing loading my modules by the way

Comment: In general, we have all services as Singleton. Thus, such services must be a part of Core Module! Small tip: Core is for everything that should be singleton through the whole angular application: services, navbar, footer and so on.

Comment: what if i need access to sharedModule inside coreModule... Currently i get circular dependency errors. Should i keep trying to do this or is it inherently wrong?

Comment: Best example I've read so far, cheers!

Answer (score 3):

### For Components ##

If you want to use your component in multiple modules, then you can define it in a `SharedModule`, declare and export it.

### For Modules

You can (but don't need to) export the angular modules `CommonModule, FormsModule etc.` from your `FeatureModule`. If you import this `FeatureModule` in any `OtherModule`, all the exported modules would be automatically imported to `OtherModule`.

You can always import the angular modules separately in each module. However, if you are using a similar bunch of modules in other feature modules, I would suggest to import all modules into a shared module and use it everywhere else.

Comment: Can you rewrite my core, shared and app module for better clarification? Thanks

Comment: I'm lazing loading my modules by the way